# How to add current tab url to chrome.tabs.create url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I have added a conext menu in Chrome that when clicked opens a Wufoo form using chrome.tabs.create.  One of the fields I need the user to complete in the wufoo form is the URL of the current tab.  So I can simply ad my var a to the url and it should be added.  This works if var a is just some text but when I try to add the current tab url "undefined" is added to the url.  What is my mistake? How do I get the tab url to be added?

Here is the javascript

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tabs){  
var a = chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId':chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
function(tabs){
  return(tabs[0].url);
 }
 );
    if ( info.menuItemId === 'Add a Link' ) 
            chrome.tabs.create( {url:  "https://ownthistown.wufoo.com/forms/m3u64zc05w2a0a/def/field10=" + a  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use return variable from an inner function like that. You will have to do something like this

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tabs){
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (tabs) {
      if(info.menuItemId === 'Add a Link')
        chrome.tabs.create({url:  "https://ownthistown.wufoo.com/forms/m3u64zc05w2a0a/def/field10=" + tabs[0].url });
  });
});
```

Comment: that worked,.  if I waned to be able to add selected text from the web page and the url name (or title, not sure what its called) how could I do that in this function?

Comment: `info.selectionText` gives access to highlighted text and `if(info.menuItemId == "contextselection")` will make sure that there is some text selected when contextmenu is displayed